# How to test $interval with Jasmine in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have a service Home and inside it, I have selectInterval function like so:

```
Home.selectInterval = function () {
    var interval = $interval(function () {
        if (angular.element('.ui-select-toggle').length > 0) {
            angular.element('.ui-select-toggle').bind('click', function () {
                if (angular.element('.ui-select-choices-row').length > 0) {
                    angular.element('.ui-select-choices-group').mCustomScrollbar();
                }
            });
            $interval.cancel(interval);
        }
    }, 50);
};
```

Right now I am testing it like this:

```
  it('selectInterval() should be called.', function () {
    Home.selectInterval();
    $interval.flush(50);
    $rootScope.$apply();
    expect(Home.selectInterval).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // need to test $interval as well
});
```

I want to test if function is called and also $interval worked fine. Right now It giving me this error.

```
Some of your tests did a full page reload!
```

Comment: That ... is a weird test. You're calling `Home.selectInterval`, then testing to see if `Home.selectInterval` was called... Which is great, but is part of the language and probably doesn't need to be tested. More likely you want to test things like if `angular.element('.ui-select-toggle').length === 0` that it does not call `$interval.cancel(interval)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this test is what is causing your issue.  Whenever I have seen that error it is because there is some code that is changing the url.  Setting something like `$window.location.href` or `$location.path('/new-path')` will cause the phantomjs browser to do a page reload which there just isn't any support to handle right now.

If you find this is the issue, you just need to try to spy the method and it will never actually call it.  That specifically works for `$location.path('/new-path')`